# Migrated wordpress site having problems with permalinks which gets rewritten after an interval

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I migrated a wordpress website www.dot10tech.com which was initially hosted in a domain (coddets.com). I did a find-and-replace on the whole database and changed it to http://www.dot10tech.com. The site wouldnt load but I could get into wp-admin Dashboard. I followed a popular suggestion of "changing the permalink structure and reverting it back" and the site loaded. But after 5-10 mins the site showed "Unable to serve this request" and AGAIN I went to dashboard, did the permalinks...site was up...after 5-10 mins...the cycle continues...PLEASE help

Comment: Go to wp-config.php and on wp_debug mode on and then let us know what is the error.

Comment: Its showing "Site temporarily unavailable.Connection timed out - please try again"...I followed some online guides and increased max execution time and memory limit to higher values. All the time the site gets up whenever I save the permalink structure inside the wordpress admin. After 10 mins , the same problem comes up again..I have been trying all I can the past days, thats why the late reply..please help..

Comment: Do one thing go to your hosting support team show theme this error. I guess there is issue with port. Port is blocked by firewall settings due to that this is creating issue.

Comment: Turns out it was actually a caching plugin (W3 Total Cache) causing the error, I deactivated and removed the plugin and updated the permalink settings. Now I gave it a decent 48hrs and the site is working fine!